# How to call a feature file using a for loop. The feature file being called will also accept parameters from the feature file calling it

Tags: karate

example :

Contents of FooGetRequest.feature file

```
* eval for (var i=0; i<foobarInDB.length; i++) call read('../features/BarGetRequest.feature') { foo_code:'#(foo_code)' , bar_code:'#(foobarInDB[i])'}
```

This is how BarGetRequest.feature file looks like :

```
Background:
    * url baseUrl

Given path 

"/v1/foo/"+foo_code+"/skus/"+bar_code+"/bar"
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

When I execute FooGetRequest.feature file i get the following error

```
[java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: Expected ; but found read
```

Comment: I have edited my answer pls check if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small java script to return me a map like { foo : bar}

```
* def fun = function(x){return {foo :x }}
* def fooBarMap = karate.map(fooBarMap,fun)
* def validateResponse = call read('../features/BarGetRequest.feature) propertySkuMap
```

and in the BarGetRequest.feature I read the values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use driven data driven feature in karate for loop over feature multiple times

Assuming `foobarInDB` is an array of `bar_code` and `foo_code` will always be same

```
* set foobarInDB[*].foo_code = foo_code
* call read('../features/BarGetRequest.feature') foobarInDB
```

refer [Data driven feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features)